# Is there any way to know if a string is not translated?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have my own module that I want to translate to some languages. I use the [`t`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function and also I have my *lang.po* files.

I try to update the *lang.po* files every time I use the `t` function but maybe I forget to update some text string.

Is there any way to know if there are some *t-strings* without translation in the *lang.po* files?

I can go to `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` but I only need to check the strings of my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [l10n_client](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client) then flush your cache.

If you switch to any other language you'll see a small box with blue bg in the bottom right. Click it and in the left it'll show all translated & untranslated strings. The green ones have been translated, while other ones you'll need to. Just select one and add the translation there itself.